# How to get "canonical unix shell" for Python

Tags: python, shell

According to the documentation for the `subprocess` module, its default shell is `/bin/sh`, but I have an ingrained, and probably irrational, aversion to hard-coding such constants.

Therefore, I much prefer to refer to some constant defined in `subprocess`.  I have not been able to find any way to interrogate `subprocess` *directly* for this constant.  The best I've managed is

```
def _getshpath():
    return subprocess.check_output('which sh', shell=True).strip()
```

or

```
def _getshpath():
    return subprocess.check_output('echo "$0"', shell=True).strip()
```

...both of which look pathetically fragile, since their validity ultimately depend on precisely the specific value I'm trying to determine in the first place.  (I.e., if the value of this executable is not "/bin/sh", either definition could easily be nonsensical.)

What's best-practice for getting this path (without hard-coding it as "/bin/sh")?

Thanks!

Comment: `subprocess` itself hardcodes the path as `/bin/sh`. Maybe you should do the same or just use one of the methods you describe :)

Comment: Where is that path hard-coded (/bin/sh)?  Is it a member of subprocess?

Comment: /bin/sh should be the standard POSIX shell, so you can't go wrong with that in a POSIX environment. In any other environment... who knows?

Comment: @ncRubert: no, it's just used as a string in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard-coding it as /bin/sh is perfectly valid.  If you look at the documentation for C's popen() you'll find it does this too.  /bin/sh is, by construction, the system's standard shell.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
>>> import os
>>> shell = os.environ['SHELL']
>>> print shell
'/bin/bash'
```

You can use this to set the `executable` argument of `subprocess.Popen`.